# Proving that $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty 2^{-4^n}$ is transcendental

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, transcendental-numbers

I want to prove that the following number is transcendental: $$\alpha = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty 2^{-4^n}$$

Liouville's theorem states that if $\alpha$ is algebraic with minimal polynomial of degree $d$, then $\exists c > 0$ such that $\forall \frac{p}{q} \in \mathbb{Q}$ we have $|\alpha - \frac{p}{q}| > \frac{c}{q^d}$.

Here's my attempt: Assume $\alpha \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ where $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$. I will look at $\alpha$ in base $2$ for simplicity. We will then have $\alpha = 0.00.1010001...$.
I defined $\frac{p_r}{q_r} = \sum_{n = 1}^r2^{-4^n}$. Then $|\alpha - \frac{p}{q}| = \sum_{n = r + 1}^\infty 2^{-4^n} < 2\times2^{-4^{(r + 1)}} = \frac{2}{(2^{4^{r}})^4} = \frac{2}{q_r^4}$. Now by Liouville's theorem, we have:
$$\frac{c}{q_r^d} < |\alpha - \frac{p_r}{q_r}| < \frac{2}{q_r^4}$$
I don't know how to derive a contradiction from this. (If I haven't made any mistakes of course.) I'm also not sure if this approach works.

Comment: Of possible relevance is my answer (including the references) to [Does every normal number have irrationality measure $2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/691530/13130) @FShrike -- I'm pretty sure $\overline{\Bbb Q}$ denotes the (presumably *real*) algebraic closure of the rationals. The notation is fairly common, but probably "algebraic closure" should have prefaced its use. (For this reason, I often include "topological closure" when using this notation in MSE, at least when the context is not utterly clear to a casual reader -- [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1879325/13130).)

Comment: Perhaps instead you might want to look up *Roth*’s theorem, which is a huge improvement on Liouville’s… but is of course a lot harder to prove.

Comment: @FShrike I meant the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$. I will edit the question to make it clear.

Comment: Did you come up with this question or did you find it somewhere? This is likely quite hard, otherwise Liouville would have given this as an example of a transcendental number, rather than say $\sum 2^{-n!}$.

Comment: I agree with @BartMichels ... You cannot prove $\alpha$ is transcendental using Liouville's theorem in this obvious way.  See similar numbers in the list at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number#Numbers_proven_to_be_transcendental

Comment: @BartMichels It was given to us as a problem in undergraduate algebraic number theory but I don't know the original source. We've only used Liouville's theorem to prove things like this for now.

Comment: this is an immediate consequence of Roth theorem (more generally if $f(n)>0$ and $\liminf_{n \to \infty}\frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)} >2$ then $\sum 2^{-f(n)}$ is transcendental as a consequence of Roth theorem

Comment: Roth's Theorem night be a bit of a sledgehammer here. Have you looked at this nice [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1303.1685) ?